# Postman: UTC checker

Tags: json, postman

I've been searching for the best solution regarding this:

```
{
  startDate: *insert UTC here*
}
```

In my Postman test, I need to verify if my `startDate` is in UTC format.

Comment: What do you mean by UTC format? What have you tried so far? What does this look like in Postman? What is the actual response data structure? Creating a question lacking details is not searching for a solution, it's waiting for one.

Comment: first i try to used string function includes but postman doesn't support it.
UTC format 2018-02-28T00:00:00.000Z like this,
tests["Same start date"]                           =jsonData.data.startDate.includes(start_date_value);
first attempt: using includes

Comment: " postman doesn't support it"...what do you mean? PostMan will send whatever values you tell it to. What's the context? What error are you getting? Edit the question to include proper code, error messages and a clear explanation of what you're actually trying to achieve. Thankyou.

Comment: It's straight forward to post an answer that involves matching a specific string format using regex but it's horrible and pointless, if that's not what you need. Without more details, it's difficult for anyone to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a terrible way of checking a date format using regex, I wouldn't recommend doing this but it *would* work:

```
var dateFormat = "2018-02-28T00:00:00.000Z"
pm.test("match UTC Format", () => {
    pm.expect(dateFormat).to.match(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}Z/)
})
```

This has been run against the Windows native client, if you're still using the chrome extension it will not work as this doesn't have the `pm.*` API.

In your Test, you can replace the demo `dateFormat` variable that I've used with `jsonData.data.startDate` from your example in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

using Javascript date object to validate a date.
It will pass only if it is formatted well AND also a that it contains real date.

```
stringWithISODate = '2020-10-23T00:00:00.000Z';
thedate = new Date(stringWithISODate);
theDateString = thedate.toISOString();
if (stringWithISODate == theDateString) {
    console.log('yea it is ISO');
}



stringWithUTCDate = 'Fri, 23 Oct 2020 00:00:00 GMT';
thedate = new Date(stringWithUTCDate);
theDateString = thedate.toUTCString();
if (stringWithUTCDate == theDateString) {
    console.log('yea it is UTC');
}
```